# Python 2.7 UnicodeEncode error

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a letter n with tilde (ñ) stored in a field in my database, and my Django application is giving some problems when trying to use it as a string.

When I access the value in the REPL it shows up like this:

```
>>> person.last_name
u'xxxxxxa\xf1oxxxx'
>>> str(person.last_name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in     position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong please - I'm thinking that it's a problem that the `\xf1` string is contained inside of a Unicode string, and that it should've been handled differently *prior* to this value becoming a Unicode string... but I don't know if that's a symptom or the actual disease, as it were.

And so I'm not sure what to do about this. Am I perhaps *storing* this value incorrectly in the first place? Maybe I just need someone to show me how to decode it correctly? My goal is to write this value to a CSV, which ultimately involves running it through `str()`. Thanks very much!

Comment: The easiest way is changing to python3. There are only several months before python2's deadline.

Comment: It's on our roadmap, but this info will perhaps help me propel the need a bit more. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character ñ is unicode character [`LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm) (U+00F1). So the unicode string you see is correct. Python shows the escape \xf1, actually meaning in the context of a unicode string, character U+00F1.

There is nothing to decode, rather if you want to write that unicode string to some byte stream such as a file, you need to *encode* it.

The issue comes from taking `str(foo)` where `foo` is a unicode string. This is equivalent to `foo.encode('ascii')`. However, character ñ does not exist in ASCII encoding, thus the error you have.

Instead if you want a binary, encoded representation of your unicode string, you must know which encoding you want and encode manually:

```
>>> foo = u'xxxxxxa\xf1oxxxx'
>>> foo.encode('utf8')
'xxxxxxa\xc3\xb1oxxxx'
>>> foo.encode('latin1')
'xxxxxxa\xf1oxxxx'
```

Simply be sure to use the encoding of your CSV file, otherwise you'll have invalid characters.

The same will be true with python 3 btw, only your unicode string will be `str` type and your encoded string will be `bytes` type:

```
>>> foo = u'xxxxxxa\xf1oxxxx'  # note the u prefix is accepted for compatibility but has no effect
>>> foo.encode('utf8')
b'xxxxxxa\xc3\xb1oxxxx'
>>> foo.encode('latin1')
b'xxxxxxa\xf1oxxxx'
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped. My final resolution was to use a try/except block to capture that UnicodeDecode error, and just re-try the line of code, but without running it through `str()` - wouldn't have thought of that without you making it clear that that was my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple python `encode` function to convert `unicode` to `str`. Second parameter `ignore` is give to ignore character which python can't encode in that particular format.

```
In [1]: foo = u'xxxxxxa\xf1oxxxx'

In [2]: foo.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
Out[2]: 'xxxxxxaoxxxx'

In [3]: foo.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
Out[3]: 'xxxxxxa\xc3\xb1oxxxx'
```